# Call to replace comma with nothing in C# not working

Tags: c#

My code below is supposed to take a number string input and then check if the string has decimals or commas then if true it should replace them with nothing or just get rid of them then it should keep adding leading zeroes to the string until the length of the numbers in the string is equal to 13. My code prints `000123,560789`for input `12,560.789` which is an incorrect output because the comma shouldn't be there.

```
using System;

public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string xcom = "123,560.789";
        Console.WriteLine(FormatNumber(xcom));
    }
    static string FormatNumber(string text){
        string prm = text;
        string ret = string.Empty;
        if(prm.Contains(",")){
            ret = prm.Replace(",","");
        }
        if(prm.Contains(".")){
            ret = prm.Replace(".","");
        }
        //keep adding trailing zeroes till the length is 13
        while(ret.Length<13){
            ret = "0"+ret ;
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's because you don't feed the output of your first if statement into the second one, you effectively overwrite what you did in the first one.

Comment: Please re-read the [mre] guidance on posting code for future questions. While code in the question is better than average in SO questions, there is way too much extra code. I.e. you don't need the function, there is really no need for `if` and `while` part is unrelated. Really just 4 lines `var prm = ",."; ret = prm.Replace(",","");ret = prm.Replace(".",""); Console.Write(ret);` should be enough. Note that at this point of creating the sample you potentially could have spotted the typo... or clarify the question (i.e. you *expected* `prm` to change).

Comment: Side note: obviously for non-homework assignment you should not be doing that at all and instead parse number to a number and then use ToString with desired culture/format to get the result.

Comment: I understand I need to use the result of the first function where I replaced the comma with nothing, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `ret` instead of `prm` in second if, also it is better to consistently work with the same variable for checks:

```cs
string ret = prm;
...
if(ret.Contains("."))
{
    ret = ret.Replace(".","");
}
```

Otherwise you are working with the unmodified instance (i.e. original string - in `ret = prm.Replace(".", "");`, `prm` is not affected by previous `Replace`, strings are immutable in C# - [check out the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/#immutability-of-strings)).

And the checks are not needed here, just chain the `Replace` calls:

```cs
string ret = prm.Replace(",","").Replace(".","");
```

And you can use `string.PadLeft(Int32, Char)` instead of writing it manually:

```cs
string ret = prm.Replace(",", "")
    .Replace(".", "")
    .PadLeft(13, '0');
return ret;
```

Comment: Chain calling the replace methods solved the problem for me